# Android - back arrow doesn't return to MainActivity when opened via notification

Tags: android

In android app I have let's say 2 activities - MainActivity and OtherActivity. When I press the back arrow in OtherActivity, it goes back to MainActivity, this is working fine. This is the part of code in OtherActivity:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

But when I send a notification, after clicking the notify window, OtherActivity opens - that is ok, as I want. This is caused by this code in Notifications:

```
private void sendNotification(String title, String body) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, OtherActivity.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
            0 /* Request code */,
            i,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
}
```

This works very well, but now if I press the back arrow on OtherActivity, it just exits the app and goes not to MainActivity.

I have already set the parent in manifest for OtherActivity, so I am not sure why it is not going to MainActivity:

```
   <activity
            android:name=".OtherActivity"
            android:label="OtherActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
```

Comment: Remove the call to `onBackPressed()`; you don't need it

Comment: it didn't help. If I go to OtherActivity from notify window, the back arrow doesn't open MainActivity even if I remove onBackPressed

Comment: The back arrow is supposed to be hierarchical up, not temporal back. You should set parent activity in the manifest and remove call to back.

Comment: as you can see in my code, I have set the parentactivity in manifest and I tried also to remove onbackpressed and it doesn't work. But the problem is solved in notification class - see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I think finally I found the answer. In my Sendnotification method I use this:

```
    Intent backIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    backIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, OtherActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    final PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivities(this, 1,
            new Intent[] {backIntent, notificationIntent}, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

Now this is working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The way the back button works is that it just restarts the previous activity, in the case of pressing back after opening the app from the notification the code skips the main activity and that makes it normal that the app just closes when you click back, the way to handle this would require some work at the first time but then would work like a charm for you in every other step or notification handling.

What you need to do is to create a layer that handles the launch of your app, for example `Splash Screen > Authentication > MainActivity > any other Activity (or stop at Main if first time launching and not from notification)`, that way when a user clicks on the notification, don't redirect him to the `OtherActivity` from the start, instead redirect to the `AppLauncher` for example and let the app launcher do all the previous steps to reach your `MainActivity` and then to the `OtherActivity`, that way if the user clicks back from `OtherActivity` or `OtherActivity2`, etc., he will always return to the `MainActivity` after pressing back after opening the app from a notification.

About setting a new Intent for the `onBackPressed` to re-open MainActivity, this is a terrible solution as you are creating a new `Instance` of your already open `MainActivity` and this will be a huge data leak and performance issue, you will notice the app going slower till it terminates if you keep redirecting back and forth between Main and Other Activities in this scenario.